# Url amigables de dirección desconocida

Tags: .htaccess

tengo el siguiente problema:

Necesito poner algunas URL's en forma amigable pero en una zona creo url's de forma dinámica con lo que desconozco cual será su url real.

Ejemplo de htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z/]+)/$ [urldesconocida].php
```

[urldesconocidad].php sería la url real pero al crearse de forma dinámica desconozco que dirección poner.

¿He pensado que quizás haya alguna forma de en vez de marcar la url, poner el nombre de una carpeta y que te seleccione todos aquellos archivos dentro de una carpeta?

Gracias por vuestros consejos.

Comment: Hola. Si deseas manejar direcciones amigables debes pensar en usar una única puerta de entrada para tu sitio (ej: index.php) y servirte de un enrutador interno que resuelva como tratar todas las solicitudes. Ayer respondí a una pregunta similar [Configuración correcta de htaccess para URLs amigables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/385429/91033) en dónde trato de cubrir tu necesidad, entre otras cosas.

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco si será el código más eficiente porque mis conocimientos del archivo .htaccess son limitados pero buscando he dado con la siguiente solución por si alguien le interesa.

Debemos añadir a nuestro .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/carpeta/$1.php !-f
RewriteRule ^nombrecarpetaamigable/([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ carpeta/$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Con esto convertirá en amigable cualquier archivo .php que se situe en dicha carpeta sin tener que añadir uno por uno cada uno de los archivos .php

Un saludo.